# Application Settings | System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection Only Saves One Value

Tags: c#, settings, stringcollection

In the application settings I have a setting called Locations and the type is a System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection.

I also have a textbox and a button that are supposed to add values to the StringCollection.

After entering the value into the textbox, the value is supposed to be added into a listbox and into the StringCollection. The code for adding a new value to the listbox and StringCollection is as follow:

```
       string newPrintLocation = tbAddPrintLocation.Text;

        if (lbPrintLocations.Items.Contains(newPrintLocation) == false)
        {
            lbPrintLocations.Items.Add(newPrintLocation);

            Properties.Settings.Default.Locations.Add(newPrintLocation);

            cbPrintLocation.Items.Add(newPrintLocation);

            tbAddPrintLocation.Clear();
        }
```

The goal is when the user restarts the form the values are added back into the listbox. Currently this is the code that I use to try to achieve that:

```
           foreach (var item in Properties.Settings.Default.Locations)
        {
            lbPrintLocations.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

The problem is that only the first value gets added to the listbox but none of the rest. At this point I have no idea what I am doing wrong. So I was wondering if someone could help me out or point me to the right direction.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Quartermain.

Comment: Do you call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` anywhere? When you debug the loop to populate `lbPrintLocations` (you did step through the loop in the debugger, right?) what did you see? How many items are actually in the collection? Note that without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it won't be possible for anyone to actually tell you what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I forgot to call Properties.Settings.Default.Save()... Thank you!